# how do i add a posward to Guest Login?

Tags: password

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit Configured operating System.
Here  i would like to ask two questions.
1. how can i set a password to Guest Login?
2.is there any possibilities also add passwords for drives in partition?

Comment: I don't think you can set a password for the Guest account. The whole point of the Guest account is to be passwordless. As for drive passwords, you'd have to encrypt them in order to require a password to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "guest" account that you can keep as a normal user (not a guest user) by making a user named "guest" and setting a password on that, though, and then potentially restricting their access. You can then disable the normal "guest account". (The guest account system however will never have a password.

For tips on how to add a user  go here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto